# make Image Button visible if value is present in shared preferences (Android)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, imagebutton

I am fairly new to Android development and am trying to create a for loop that checks each key in a shared preferences file and sets the Image Button to visible that corresponds to the value in each key.

Example:

```
ImageButton button101 = (ImageButton) findViewByID(R.id.button101);
```

If the value 101 is in any of the keys in my shared preferences file, I need button101 to be set to visible. Where I am stuck is that I can't seem to figure out how to reference button101 based on the value. I tried something like this without success:

```
String.valueOf("button" + sharedPrefs.getInt("key", 0)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the reference to your image first, then set it to visible or not (I think you are just doing things out of order):

```
String key = String.valueOf("button" + sharedPrefs.getInt("key", 0));
ImageButton button101 = (ImageButton) findViewByID(key);
button101.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I think `findViewById` only accepts an `int` matching the Resource ID of the view. In order to search for views by their tag or text they contain you'll need to dereference their parent View.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted based on your advice and had to change to findViewWithTag, but it's working perfectly now.

Comment: Great. Glad you got it working.  Android can be challenging at times, so stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
String key = String.valueOf("button" + sharedPrefs.getInt("key", 0));
ImageButton button101 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.key);
button101.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```